# Using Math.Abs in Linq.Expressions.Expression - dynamic query creation

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I am using Expression to create dynamic queries programmatically.

```
Expression.Subtract(exp1, exp2);
```

In one requirement, I need to use Absolute value of the expression. Something like -

```
Math.Abs(Expression.Subtract(exp1, exp2));
```

But I am getting below error in it-

> The best overloaded method match for System.Math.Abs(decimal)' has
>   some invalid arguments

Comment: You surely want an `Expression.Call`, not the absolute value of an `Expression`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to call `Math.Abs()` on the *expression*. You want to create an expression *representing the call* to `Math.Abs()` with the result of the `Subtract` expression.

So at first you need to find the correct overload of `Math.Abs()`, the one taking an argument of the type returned by your subtract expression:

```
var sub = Expression.Subtract(exp1, exp2);
MethodInfo abs = typeof(Math).GetMethod("Abs", new[]{sub.Type});
if (abs == null)
    // error handling here: no matching method found
```

`sub.Type` is the return type of the subtract expression.

Then you can create the call expression:

```
var call = Expression.Call(null, abs, sub);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to call `Math.Abs` on `x - y`, not on the `Expression`. As the method `Abs` within the type `Math` is `static`, you don´t need an instance to call it, which is why the first parameter to the `CallExpression` is null.

Thus do this:

```
var subtractExp = Expression.Subtract(exp1, exp2);
var m = typeof(Math).GetMethod("Abs", new[] { subtractExp.Type });
var exp = Expression.Call(null, m, subtractExp);
```

Comment: I'm sure you need to tell `GetMethod("Abs")` the argument types or you get an `AmbiguousMatchException`.

Comment: so how do you now that the subtraction results in `int`?